Set element width based on a string that is not in the element
I have a React component that can render one string or another.
const MyComponent = (props: {
    readonly textA: string;
    readonly textB: string;
    readonly renderB: boolean;
}) => {
    return <>{props.renderB ? props.textB : props.textA}</>;
};

The problem is when I use this and I toggle renderB on and off, the width of the component can change based on which string is rendered. I want the component width to fit the longer of the two strings.
How can I take the max length of textA and textB and use that to determine the width of my component?
For example, it could look something like this:
const MyComponent = (props: {
    readonly textA: string;
    readonly textB: string;
    readonly renderB: boolean;
}) => {
    const widthA = /* compute the width of props.textA */;
    const widthB = /* compute the width of props.textB */;

    return (
        <div style={{ width: `${Math.max(widthA, widthB)}px` }}>
            {props.renderB ? props.textB : props.textA}
        </div>
    );
};


There's not enough detail on why you need to set the width explicitly (assuming there's more components inside the div), but this really looks like it be solved by using the correct layout with correct CSS instead of calculating the width in JS.

Normally elements will size themselves based on their content. In this case, I need to size the element based on a string that may not be in the actual element. I don't know how to do that.

Ah I see what you mean now, did not read the question careful enough : \

One solution is to use grid layout, render both child span, and hide the one that shouldn't be rendered (using visibility:hidden). The advantage is that this can be done pure CSS without needing to calculate the Text size, which is usually pretty troublesome and buggy. But the drawback is of course the user can see the other child in the DOM tree, which might not be ideal depending on your use case.


.wrapper {
  display: inline-grid;
  border: 1px solid red; /* for showing the size*/
}

.wrapper>span {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  text-wrap: nowrap;
}

.wrapper>span:not(.rendered) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
<span class="wrapper"> 
  <span>Short Text</span>
  <span class="rendered">Example 1. Long text I'm very long</span>
</span>
<span class="wrapper"> 
  <span class="rendered">Example 2. Short Text</span>
  <span>Very Long textttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
</span>



Code sample
const MyComponent = (props: {
    readonly textA: string;
    readonly textB: string;
    readonly renderB: boolean;
}) => {
    return (
        <span style={{ display: 'inline-grid' }}>
            <span
                style={{
                    gridColumn: 1,
                    gridRow: 1,
                    visibility: props.renderB ? 'hidden' : 'visible',
                }}
            >
                {props.textA}
            </span>
            <span
                style={{
                    gridColumn: 1,
                    gridRow: 1,
                    visibility: props.renderB ? 'visible' : 'hidden',
                }}
            >
                {props.textB}
            </span>
        </span>
    );
};


Nice solution. I imagine this is computationally cheaper than creating a canvas and measuring the text, plus it doesn't require any a priori font information. I'll just add in a code example for completeness, then accept this answer.

Thanks! Your solution might actually solve me a problem I’m facing now that I need to overlay divs over texts that are rendered by ZPL lol.

You can use a canvas to measure the width of text. The component from the question can be filled in as follows:
const MyComponent = (props: {
    readonly textA: string;
    readonly textB: string;
    readonly renderB: boolean;
}) => {
    const maxWidth = (() => {
        const context = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
        if (context) {
            context.font = '16px Roboto';
        }
        return Math.round(
            Math.max(
                context?.measureText(props.textA).width ?? 0,
                context?.measureText(props.textB).width ?? 0,
            ),
        );
    })();

    return (
        <span
            style={{
                display: 'inline-block',
                width: `${maxWidth}px`,
            }}
        >
            {props.renderB ? props.textB : props.textA}
        </span>
    );
};

The downside is that you have to set the font, which means you need to know the font of the component.
